# Window opened via GLUT with Rust FFI freezes

Tags: macos, opengl, glut, rust

The title of the question pretty much describes the scenario. I'm attempting to open an OpenGL window on OS X 10.8 using Rust's FFI and the GLUT library. The window opens, and control gets handed over to glutMainLoop, but the window doesn't draw anything (including the standard title bar with close, minimize, maximize buttons! it's just a white square) and I have to force quit the program every time. Currently the FFI I'm using is a tiny subset of the actual functionality that I scraped together by looking at other FFIs. Here's the code that I have so far:

main.rs:

```
use gl::*;
use glut::*;

fn main() {
    glut::init();
    glut::initWindowSize(640, 480);
    glut::initWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glut::initDisplayMode(glut::DOUBLE | glut::RGBA);
    glut::createWindow("Test GLUT");

    glut::displayFunc(|| {
        io::println("Display func start");
        gl::clear(gl::COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl::begin(gl::TRIANGLES);
            gl::vertex2f(-0.5, 0.0);
            gl::vertex2f(0.0, 1.0);
            gl::vertex2f(0.5, 0.0);
        gl::end();

        glut::swapBuffers();
        io::println("Swapped buffers");
    });
    gl::clearColor(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3);

    glut::keyboardFunc(|key: char, x: int, y: int| {
        if(key == 'q') {
            io::println("Pressed q");
        }
    });

    io::println("Starting main loop");
    glut::mainLoop();
}
```

glut.rs:

```
use libc::{c_int, c_uint, c_char, c_uchar};
use task::local_data::{local_data_get, local_data_set};

#[cfg(target_os="macos")]
#[nolink]
#[link_args="-framework GLUT"]
extern mod dummy {
}

fn displayFuncTlsKey(callback: @@fn()) {
    // Empty
}
extern fn displayFuncCallback() {
    unsafe {
        let callback = local_data_get(displayFuncTlsKey).get();
        (*callback)();
    }
}

fn keyboardFuncTlsKey(callback: @@fn(key: char, x: int, y: int)) {
    // Empty
}
extern fn keyboardFuncCallback(key: c_uchar, x: c_int, y: c_int) {
    unsafe {
        let callback = local_data_get(keyboardFuncTlsKey).get();
        (*callback)(key as char, x as int, y as int);
    }
}

#[nolink]
extern mod glut_unsafe {
    pub fn glutInit(argc: *c_int, argv: **c_char);
    pub fn glutInitDisplayMode(mode: c_uint);
    pub fn glutInitWindowPosition(x: c_int, y: c_int);
    pub fn glutInitWindowSize(width: c_int, height: c_int);
    pub fn glutCreateWindow(title: *c_char) -> c_int;

    pub fn glutDisplayFunc(func: *u8);
    pub fn glutKeyboardFunc(func: *u8);

    pub fn glutMainLoop();
    pub fn glutSwapBuffers();
}

mod glut {
    pub const RGB: u32 = 0;
    pub const RGBA: u32 = 0;

    pub const SINGLE: u32 = 0;
    pub const DOUBLE: u32 = 2;

    pub fn init() {
        unsafe {
            let argc = 1 as c_int;
            // I wonder how correct this is...
            let command = str::as_c_str("draw", |s| s);
            let argv: &[*c_char] = &[command, ptr::null()];
            let argv_p: **c_char = vec::raw::to_ptr(argv);
            // let argv_p: **c_char = cast::reinterpret_cast(&ptr::to_unsafe_ptr(&argv));
            // let argv: (*u8, *u8) = (vec::raw::to_ptr(command), ptr::null());
            // let argv_p: **c_char = cast::reinterpret_cast(&ptr::to_unsafe_ptr(&(command, ptr::null)));

            glut_unsafe::glutInit(ptr::to_unsafe_ptr(&argc), argv_p);
        }
    }

    pub fn initWindowSize(width: int, height: int) {
        unsafe {
            glut_unsafe::glutInitWindowSize(width as c_int, height as c_int)
        }
    }
    pub fn initWindowPosition(x: int, y: int) {
        unsafe {
            glut_unsafe::glutInitWindowPosition(x as c_int, y as c_int)
        }
    }
    pub fn initDisplayMode(mode: u32) {
        unsafe {
            glut_unsafe::glutInitDisplayMode(mode as c_uint)
        }
    }

    pub fn createWindow(title: &str) -> int {
        let mut bytes = str::as_c_str(title, {|s| s});
        unsafe {
            glut_unsafe::glutCreateWindow(bytes) as int
        }
    }

    pub fn displayFunc(func: @fn()) {
        unsafe {
            local_data_set(displayFuncTlsKey, @func);
            glut_unsafe::glutDisplayFunc(displayFuncCallback)
        }
    }
    pub fn keyboardFunc(func: @fn(key: char, x: int, y: int)) {
        unsafe {
            local_data_set(keyboardFuncTlsKey, @func);
            glut_unsafe::glutKeyboardFunc(keyboardFuncCallback)
        }
    }

    pub fn mainLoop() {
        unsafe {
            glut_unsafe::glutMainLoop()
        }
    }
    pub fn swapBuffers() {
        unsafe {
            glut_unsafe::glutSwapBuffers()
        }
    }
}
```

Any help figuring out why this is happening would be awesome. A similar thing happened when I was trying to use bindings to glfw as well, so I think I might be doing something basic wrong, but I have no idea what.

EDIT: This is with the bundled 0.5 tarball, not the most recent from GitHub. For some reason the most recent won't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is likely related to the thread you are running the code on. Some libraries have an affinity for the actual main thread the process began execution on, and this is often the case with graphics libraries and calls into the windowing system. The main Rust task does not execute on the main thread, but the Rust library does have a way to execute a task on the main thread. See an [example from servo](https://github.com/mozilla/servo/blob/master/src/servo/platform/osmain.rs#L340).

If that doesn't get you unstuck then you may need to create a .app folder to run your OS X application. I'm not entirely familiar with the details but I'm lead to believe that coca API's don't entirely work without one.

Comment: Thank you so much! This completely fixed the issue with GLUT. Everything is working correctly now.